# How to color the same labels on dendorgram in one colour in r

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dendrogram, dendextend

I have clustered some data in `r` and plotted the results as a dendrogram. What i am trying to find out right now is how I can change the colour of the labels, so that labels that are the same have the same colour.

I got my dendrogram using the following code:

```
> d<-stringdist::stringdistmatrix(AR_GenesforR$AR_Genes)
> cl <-hclust(as.dist(d))
> plot(cl, label=AR_GenesforR$AR_Genes)
> groups <- cutree(cl, k=2)
> rect.hclust(cl, k=2, border="red")
```

The resulting dendrogram looks like this:
[image]

What I want to do now, is to colour all labels that are the same in the same colour, eg. all `2010` in yellow, all `2011` in blue and so on. I have researched quite a bit, but mostly only found ways to colour the labels according to the clusters they are in. Does someone know how I can do what I want?

Comment: _"only found ways to colour the labels according to the clusters they are in"_ - well, why not think of the labels as clusters? Check out https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#setting-a-dendrograms-labels

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will do what you ask, based on the [dendextend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/index.html) R package (here is a short [2 page paper on the package](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/31/22/3718)).

```
x <- c(2011,2011,2012,2012,2015,2015,2015)
names(x) <- x
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(x)))

color_unique_labels <- function(dend, ...) {
    if(!require(dendextend)) install.packages("dendextend")
    if(!require(colorspace)) install.packages("colorspace")
    library("dendextend")

    n_unique_labels <- length(unique(labels(dend)))
    colors <- colorspace::rainbow_hcl(n_unique_labels)
    labels_number <- as.numeric(factor(labels(dend)))
    labels_colors(dend) <- colors[labels_number]
    dend
}


par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(dend)
dend2 <- color_unique_labels(dend)
plot(dend2)
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you! However I used the code a little different, as I cluster not on the years but on another parameter and add the years as labels (normally  do that using `plot(cluster, labels=data$column)`, but that does not work in this case. I am very new to R, but I guess the reason is that the unique labels are 'fixed' in `n_unique_labels <- length(unique(labels(dend)))`?

Comment: Ok, could resolve it with help of dendextent manual using `dend = dend %>% set("labels", data$column)`